# Relationship between eigenvalues and matrix elements (Note: eigenspectrum gap and rescaling)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sparse-matrices

Let $\textbf D$ be a square matrix with eigenvalues separated into two or more groups using their magnitude (say the first group of eigenvalues is $\{1,2,\dots,10\}$ and the second group has eigenvalues $\{1010,1021,1051,\dots,10000\}$).

Then consider the eigenvalue relation of transition matrix $\textbf{D}$,
$$\textbf{D}\textbf{R}=\textbf{R}\Lambda$$
Partitioning $\Lambda$ gives
$$\textbf{D}\textbf{R}=\textbf{R}
\begin{bmatrix}\Lambda_{dd}&\textbf{0}_{dm}\\\textbf{0}_{md}&\Lambda_{mm}\end{bmatrix}$$
wheere $\Lambda_{dd}$ has the smallest group and $\Lambda_{mm}$ has the largest group of eigenvalues. Rescale the system using $k$ (a value with magnitude greater than the small group of eigenvalues and less than large group of eigenvalues - say 100 or 1000 in the previous example of eigengroups) as
$$\frac{1}{|k|}\textbf{D}\textbf{R}=\frac{1}{|k|}\textbf{R}
\begin{bmatrix}\Lambda_{dd}&\textbf{0}_{dm}\\\textbf{0}_{md}&\Lambda_{mm}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\frac{1}{|k|}\textbf{D}\textbf{R}=\textbf{R}
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\Lambda_{dd}}{|k|}&\textbf{0}_{dm}\\\textbf{0}_{md}&\frac{\Lambda_{mm}}{|k|}\end{bmatrix}$$
Assume that $k$ infinitely large, then $\lim\limits_{|k|\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\Lambda_{dd}}{|k|}=\textbf{0}_{dd}$,

$$
\tilde{\textbf{D}}\textbf{R}=\textbf{R}\begin{bmatrix}\textbf{0}_{dd}&\textbf{0}_{dm}\\\textbf{0}_{md}&\frac{\Lambda_{mm}}{|k|}\end{bmatrix}$$

However, to rescale, I need to know what is the separation between eigenvalues to find a suitable k. This is hard in large dimensional matrices due to the need of computing a large number of eigenvalues. Then instead of checking the gap in eigenvalues, How can confirm that rescaling using the gap in elements of **D** will rescale the eigenvalues to zero.

A worked out example is given below
[image]
[image]

In the first figure, elements of **D** is sorted by their magnitude and second figure shows the eigenvalues. If I rescale **D** using $10^4$ (A  value in the second gap in the element spectrum. first gap is not useful in the case), I will get the first group of eigenvalues rescaled to zero. Then by $10^6$, I may (sometimes there will be the same number of zero eigenvalues by stepping up) rescale the second group to zero and so on.

**How can I confirm this is true in general or for some specific cases under some conditions?.**

---

A small observation about infinity.

**What is infinity?**
When we say a value $x$ is infinite, what are we meant by that?.

To my knowledge: if $x$ is defined as $\infty$, then $1/x=0$. But we know for any large number, no $x$ will satisfy this condition. There will be a decimal value at some point in $1/x$. The question is, are we considering this decimal point or not. If we are truncating it, then we can say $x=\infty$ which is an approximation.

If someone says, 100 is infinite for him, then $1/100=0.01$ is a zero for him. By using this fact I trucated the matrix **D** by removing the decimal point which satisfies the limit condition on $k$.

Comment: Is the question is "is there any direct relation or theorem that can relate the elements in $D$ and eigenvalues,  i.e. $D$ also has values which are separated into two or more groups"? I do not understant the purpose or relevance of this rounding process. The answer to this question is no. Consider the $n\times n$ matrix with all elements equal to one. It has one eigenvalue $n$ and $n-1$ eigenvalues 0. So  eigenvalues are clearly separated, but elements are not. For the identity matrix most of elements are zero but all eigenvalues are 1.

Comment: @PawelKowal: Your example has no relation to the question. First, what would be the rescaling value in the given example? Please see the derivation on scaling eigenvalue relation. If there is a separation, for sure, we can rescale the matrix D so that group of small magnitude eigenvalues rescaled to zero. But the problem is identifying the rescaling value in large dimensional problems after identifying eigenvalues. Please see the update of (what is infinity) in the question.